# Is there a way to get this solution in the SPARK-SQL, we need to apply filter after the grouping of records?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

[image]
Whenever there are 2 different values in the approval_ind column [ Y,X ] or it can be [ Y,N ] for the same Doc_Act_Checklist_Item_ID,Assigned_To_Person_ID

Then

```
1. Pick the record with entered_by_name=assigned_to_name

2. For both records if the names are matching then pick the minimum( Entered_date )

3. In the above case the names are not matching so we will pick the minimum( Entered_date ) which is Doc_Act_Checklist_Item_Person_ID = 101
```

I want to do this in SPARK-SQL please help me out of this.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM STG_PUB_CHKLST_ITEM_PERSON
WHERE Doc_Act_Checklist_Item_Person_ID = (SELECT Doc_Act_Checklist_Item_Person_ID from (SELECT *,
CASE 
WHEN ASSIGNED_TO_NAME = ENTERED_BY_NAME
THEN 'MATCH'
ELSE 'NO MATCH'
END AS MATCHING_STATUS
FROM STG_PUB_CHKLST_ITEM_PERSON
WHERE doc_act_checklist_item_id = 55
AND assigned_to_person_id = 33)
WHERE MATCHING_STATUS = 'MATCH')
;
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: I have added the code what I have tried. And that is working for the scenario 1 where the ASSIGNED_TO_NAME = ENTERED_BY_NAME is same and I'm getting the correct output.

Comment: you have provided the query that is fine but you should provide some source data and show the output that you expect for someone to help